# Print unicode characters in R

Tags: r, gsub

I try to use `gsub` to delete some characters with R. but I have some non-breaking spaces. So the following code doesn't work.

```
gsub(" ","",strings)
```

I think that in `strings`, I have some non-breaking spaces (or other kinds) rather than the usual space.

Now, if we know that there are non-breaking spaces, and we can directly use

```
gsub("<U\\+00A0>","",strings)
```

What if we don't know the unicode of the characters that we want to delete.

So in general, I would like to know how to get the unicode from a string i R.

For spaces for example, there are different kinds of them:
[image]

And sometimes, I have smileys, etc.

Comment: Use `gsub("\\xA0","",strings)` or `gsub("[ \\xA0]","",strings)`, or just ``gsub("(*UCP)\\s+","",strings, perl=TRUE)``

Comment: thank you, but my question is more general. What if we have other characters for which we don't already know the unicode ?

Comment: `gsub("(*UCP)\\s+","",strings, perl=TRUE)` removes all Unicode whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you again. and again, my question is more general, what if I see a smiley that I want to delete, how can I know get the unicode ?

Comment: What do you mean? That you need to remove any non-ASCII char? `gsub("[^\\x00-~]+", "", text)`?